# Is Amazon Elastic Transcoder returning misspelled job statuses?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, transcoding

I'm working on a video conversion feature that uses Amazon Elastic Transcoder to convert uploaded videos to a more suitable format.

The problem is that when I send a request to check the status of a transcoding job, the response does not match the API documentation. Here is a (trimmed) PHP `var_dump` of the Amazon's response following a successful transcoding job:

```
array(1) {
  ["Job"]=>
    ["Output"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["Key"]=>
      string(22) "CR13-5186d070.mp4"
      ["PresetId"]=>
      string(20) "1351620000000-000020"
      ["Rotate"]=>
      string(4) "auto"
      ["Status"]=>
      string(8) "Complete"      <---------- The API documentation says "Completed"
      ["StatusDetail"]=>
      NULL
      ["ThumbnailPattern"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

The status returned is "Complete", but the documentation says that it should actually be "Completed". From [here:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/get-job.html#get-job-responses)

> The status of the job. The value of Status is one of the following:
>   Submitted, Progressing, **Completed,** Canceled, or Error.

Is Amazon sending the wrong response?